# Installing Zend Optimizer on MAMP 2.1

Tags: zend-framework, mamp, zend-optimizer

I just upgraded to MAMP Pro 2 and have noticed that they are no longer supporting Zend Optimizer due to Apache 64bit or something along those lines.

Anyways, I have a website that needs it and I have no idea of how to go about installing Zend Optimizer on MAMP 2 and just did a tutorial which made Apache break and stop working after I ran some command in terminal so I had to reinstall my MAMP set up.

I am currently running PHP 5.2.17.

Any help would be great :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since your application also requires an old version of PHP, the easiest solution would be to install the previous version of [MAMP 1.9](http://www.mamp.info/downloads/releases/MAMP_MAMP_PRO_1.9.6.1.dmg.zip) which includes PHP 5.2.17 and Zend Optimizer 3.3.9.

The older version of MAMP is 32-bit only but should still run fine under Lion/Mountain Lion (or at least I'm not aware of any obvious issues aside from not including 64-bit in the app bundle).

Comment: I ended up just using my old mamp on another machine.

Answer (score 1):

It's working! And also on the OS X Mountain Lion!
Requires PHP 5.2.17

[Zend Optimizer for Mac OS X](http://www.joomla-show.ru/item/34-ustanavlivaem-zend-optimizer-v-mamp-mac-osx-lion-1072)

Answer (score 1):

Here step-to-step I helped myself with installing Zend Guard Loader. I also do the same processes for Zend Optimizer. I hope you find it helpful.

[Solutions I've written](http://www.quora.com/How-do-you-install-Zend-Guard-Zend-Optimizer-on-MAMP-so-that-you-can-locally-host-Zend-encrypted-files/answer/Anh-Ho)

Comment: Could you also provide a short summary of what is in the link?  The problem is that links often break. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer , section "Provide context for links".